# Extension method on list?

Tags: f#, extension-methods

How do I define an extension method on F# lists?

A naive attempt like this results in error:

```
type list with
    member this.abc() = 100
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
type List<'a> with
    member this.abc() = 100
```

You can use the qualified name `Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.List<'a>` as well, but the type abbreviation `list<'a>` can't be used.

That said, using module functions is more idiomatic. You should make a module function to easily combine with other functions through pipe `(|>)` operators:

```
module List = 
    let abc (xs: _ list) = 100
```

Answer (score 2):

```
type Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.List<'T> with
  member x.IsNotEmpty() = not (List.isEmpty x)

let xs = [1]
xs.IsNotEmpty
```